# Go deeper into object

Tags: php

I'm not great with Objects so I was wondering if somebody could help me.

I'm looking to echo out the data from this object, the previous level was classed as protected as well, I have got around that but I can't seem to pull anything out from the new object within.

Original code to gain the object:

```
$addrProp = $reflObj->getProperty('images');
$addrProp->setAccessible(true);
echo("<strong>Images:</strong>");
var_dump($addrProp->getValue($property));
```

The output:

```
array(17) {
  ["474sp1190714.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372"]=>
  object(tabs\api\property\Image)#350 (7) {
    ["filename":protected]=>
    string(106) "474sp1190714.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372"
    ["title":protected]=>
    string(8) "P1190714"
    ["alt":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["url":protected]=>
    string(74) "http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/image/normal/1000x750/474sp1190714.jpg"
    ["height":protected]=>
    int(750)
    ["width":protected]=>
    int(1000)
    ["apiPath":protected]=>
    string(35) "http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk"
  }
  ["474sp1190718.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372"]=>
  object(tabs\api\property\Image)#351 (7) {
    ["filename":protected]=>
    string(106) "474sp1190718.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372"
    ["title":protected]=>
    string(8) "P1190718"
    ["alt":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["url":protected]=>
    string(74) "http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/image/normal/1000x750/474sp1190718.jpg"
    ["height":protected]=>
    int(750)
    ["width":protected]=>
    int(1000)
    ["apiPath":protected]=>
    string(35) "http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk"
  }
```

Any examples of individual output (foreach or something) would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the properties are protected then that means that you won't be able to access them publically. You'll need to create your own public 'getters' and 'setters'. For example, in your 'tabs\api\propert\Image' object you could do the following:

```
// Because this is within the object, it has scope of the protected properties.
public function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
}
```

Then you can call getTitle() on the object to return the string contained within the title property.

This page on the PHP site may be helpful for you:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Seems to be getting an error from the function, error reporting is turned off and I have no access to this :/

Comment: From what function? With regards to error reporting, have you tried using ini_set to override error reporting?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's on now. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in"

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: That implies that you've put the function/method in the wrong place - it's a syntax error. It should be contained within the curly braces of your Image class.

Comment: I am not using a class for my images

Comment: According to the code sample you provided you are. It's the 'tabs\api\property\Image' class.